# json data extraction and pass to C# using ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, indexeddb

I have a json data which i get from an IndexedDb data source. When i do Json.stringify i get the result as

```
[{"key":1,"value":{"itemcode":"ItemA3","serialno":"erw33","saledate":"2020-05-03","id":1}},{"key":2,"value":{"itemcode":"ItemA4","serialno":"erewrwerwer","saledate":"2020-05-03","id":2}}]
```

I wish to extract only the value part from this string and using an ajax call i wish to transfer the same to a c# function with an array args.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'Export.aspx/GetDetails',
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: "{detls:" + serializedData + "}",
             success: function (r) {
                 alert("yes");
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(errorThrown);
             }
         });
```

The c# function is

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string  GetDetails(string [] detls)
{
 //get  itemcode , serialno , saledate , id  
  return "s";
}
```

I am getting Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Extract `value` using `forEach` loop.

```
let serializedData = [];
dataFromIndexedDb.forEach(item => {
    serializedData.push(item.value);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(serializedData));
```

`dataFromIndexedDb` is data from `IndexedDb` data source.

Comment: It now returns 

[{"itemcode":"ItemA3","serialno":"erw33","saledate":"2020-05-03","id":1},{"itemcode":"ItemA4","serialno":"erewrwerwer","saledate":"2020-05-03","id":2}]
But i still get Internal server error. And I hope its because the C# function dowsnt match the parameter for ajax call. How can i get this  stringified data in c#

Comment: Hi. You could try changing the parameter to array of objects `GetDetails(object [] detls)`. It is not solution, only the way to check if `GetDetails` method is called. If it works you could convert objects to `string` in code behind, or set again parameter as array of `string`-s and populate `serializedData` this way `serializedData.push(JSON.stringify(item.value));`.